# Three js object turning black when applying Phong Shading

Tags: javascript, three.js, vertex-shader, phong, threejs-editor

I have a project that basically displays 3 cubes and if i press A i alternate the material of the cubes between a MeshLambertMaterial and a MeshPhongMaterial. The problem is whenever i create the phong material and add the shadding itself the object turns black and i dont get wwhy, because i calculate the normals of vertices before hand

I know the code is very big but ignore the code overall, the important part is this function changeMaterial, because thats where the phong shadding is applied

Important part:

```
function changeMaterial(change) {
    for (i = 0; i < figures.length; i++)
    {
        if (change)
        {
            figures[i].material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( {color: 0xff0000} );
            figures[i].material.shading = THREE.FlatShading;
            figures[i].material.shading = THREE.SmoothShading;
            figures[i].geometry.normalsNeedUpdate = true;
            figures[i].geometry.computeVertexNormals();
        }
        else
        {
            figures[i].material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {color: 0xff0000} );
            figures[i].geometry.computeVertexNormals();
            figures[i].geometry.normalsNeedUpdate = true;
            console.log(figures[i].geometry);
            figures[i].material.specular = 0x111111;
            figures[i].material.shininess = 10;
            figures[i].material.shading = THREE.FlatShading;
            figures[i].material.shading = THREE.SmoothShading;
            figures[i].material.needsUpdate = true;
            figures[i].geometry.normalsNeedUpdate = true;
            console.log(figures[i].geometry);
        }
    }
}
```

Program:

```
/*global THREE*/

var camera = [];
var scene= [];
var renderer, currentCamera = 0;
let cameraRatio = 10;

var viewSize = 50;
var aspectRatio;

var geometry, material, mesh;
var wiredObjects = [];

var leftArrow, rightArrow, upArrow, downArrow;
var clock = new THREE.Clock();

var defaultScale = 1;
var universe;
var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
var controls;
var fig1;
var fig2;
var wood_texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load("./media/wood.jpg");
var glass_texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load("./media/glass.jpg");
var direc_light;
var directionalLight;
var direc_intensity = 0.5;
var figures = [];
var change_material = true;
var qKey,wKey,eKey,rKey,tKey,yKey;
var reset = false;
let pause = false;
var OrtogonalCamera;

'use strict';

function createFloor(obj, x, y, z) {
    geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(30,0.5, 40);
    material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { map: wood_texture } );
    mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    mesh.position.set(x, y, z);
    obj.add(mesh);
}

function createPalanque(obj, x, y, z) {
    geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(20,0.5, 20);
    let geometry2 = new THREE.BoxGeometry(15,0.5, 15);
    material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { map: glass_texture } );
    mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    mesh.position.set(x, y, z);
    mesh2 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry2, material);
    mesh2.position.set(x, y+2, z);
    obj.add(mesh);
    obj.add(mesh2);
}

function createMesh(obj,name,type,posx,posy,posz,rotX,rotY,rotZ,mat)
{
    let shape = new THREE.Shape();
    let width;
    const pos = new THREE.Vector3();
    const extrudeSettings = {
        depth: 0.002,
        bevelEnabled: true,
        bevelSegments: 1,
        steps: 0,
        bevelSize: 0,
        bevelThickness: 0.1
    }
    switch(name)
    {
        case 'square':
            width = 10;
            shape.moveTo(0,0);
            shape.lineTo(0,width);
            shape.lineTo(width,width);
            shape.lineTo(width,0);
            shape.lineTo(0,0);
            pos.x=-40;
            pos.y=-40;
            break;
        
        case 'triangle':
            width = 10;
            shape.moveTo(0,-width);
            shape.lineTo(0,width);
            shape.lineTo(width,0);
            shape.lineTo(0,-width);
            pos.x=0;
            pos.y=0;
            break;
    }
    let geometry;
    if (type == 1)
        geometry = new THREE.ExtrudeBufferGeometry(shape,extrudeSettings);
    if (type == 2)
        geometry = new THREE.ShapeBufferGeometry(shape);

    var shape_mat;
    if(mat == 1)
        shape_mat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xff0000, wireframe: false, side:THREE.DoubleSide});
    geometry.computeVertexNormals();
    console.log(geometry);
    mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry,shape_mat);
    mesh.position.copy(pos);
    mesh.rotateX(rotX);
    mesh.rotateY(rotY);
    mesh.rotateZ(rotZ);
    mesh.position.set(posx,posy,posz);
    mesh.name="teste";
    obj.add(mesh);
}

function render() {
    renderer.autoClear = false;
    renderer.clear();
    renderer.setViewport(0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    renderer.render(scene[0], camera[currentCamera]); // tells 3js renderer to draw scene visualization based on camera
    if (pause) {
        if (currentCamera == 1)
        {
            renderer.setViewport(0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
            renderer.render(scene[1], OrtogonalCamera2);
        }
        else
        {
            renderer.setViewport(0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
            renderer.render(scene[1],OrtogonalCamera);
        }
    }
}

function render2()
{
    renderer.render(scene[0], camera[currentCamera]);
    camera[2].update( camera[0]); 
    /* camera[currentCamera].updateWorldMatrix();
    camera[2].update(camera[currentCamera]);
    const size = new THREE.Vector2();
    renderer.getSize(size);

    renderer.setScissorTest(true);

    renderer.setScissor(0, 0, size.width / 2, size.height);
    renderer.setViewport(0, 0, size.width / 2, size.height);
    renderer.render(scene[0], camera[2].cameraL);

    renderer.setScissor(size.width, 0, size.width / 2, size.height);
    renderer.setViewport(size.width / 2, 0, size.width / 2, size.height);
    renderer.render(scene[0], camera[2].cameraR);

    renderer.setScissorTest(false); */
}

function onResize() {

    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    
    if (window.innerWidth > 0 &&  window.innerHeight > 0){
        if (camera[currentCamera] === OrtogonalCamera) {
            var i;
            var val = 2;
            aspectRatio = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
            renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
            for (i = 0; i < 1; i++) { // Ortographic Cameras
                camera[currentCamera].left = -viewSize * aspectRatio / val;
                camera[currentCamera].right = viewSize * aspectRatio / val;
                camera[currentCamera].top = viewSize / val;
                camera[currentCamera].bottom = viewSize / -val;
                camera[currentCamera].updateProjectionMatrix();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if((window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight) < 1.6) {
                camera[currentCamera].aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
                camera[currentCamera].updateProjectionMatrix();
                camera[currentCamera].lookAt(scene.position);
            }
        }
        
        camera[currentCamera].updateProjectionMatrix();
    }
}


function update()
{
    if(!pause)
    {
        var timeOccurred = clock.getDelta();
        var RotSpeed = 2.5;

        if (qKey || wKey || eKey || rKey || tKey || yKey) { // figures movement flags
            if (qKey)
                figures[0].rotation.y += RotSpeed * timeOccurred;
            if (wKey)
                figures[0].rotation.y += -RotSpeed * timeOccurred;
            
            if (eKey)
                figures[1].rotation.y += RotSpeed * timeOccurred;
            if (rKey)
                figures[1].rotation.y += -RotSpeed * timeOccurred;
            
            if (tKey)
                figures[2].rotation.y += RotSpeed * timeOccurred;
            if (yKey)
                figures[2].rotation.y += -RotSpeed * timeOccurred;
            
            if (qKey && wKey) {
                qKey = false;
                wKey = false;
            }

            if (eKey && rKey) {
                eKey = false;
                rKey = false;
            }

            if (tKey && yKey) {
                tKey = false;
                yKey = false;
            }
        }
    }
}

function changeLightning(intensity) {
    universe.getObjectByName("directional").getObjectByName("light").intensity = intensity;
}

function changeMaterial(change) {
    for (i = 0; i < figures.length; i++)
    {
        if (change)
        {
            figures[i].material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( {color: 0xff0000} );
            figures[i].material.shading = THREE.FlatShading;
            figures[i].material.shading = THREE.SmoothShading;
            figures[i].geometry.normalsNeedUpdate = true;
            figures[i].geometry.computeVertexNormals();
        }
        else
        {
            figures[i].material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {color: 0xff0000} );
            figures[i].geometry.computeVertexNormals();
            figures[i].geometry.normalsNeedUpdate = true;
            console.log(figures[i].geometry);
            figures[i].material.specular = 0x111111;
            figures[i].material.shininess = 10;
            figures[i].material.shading = THREE.FlatShading;
            figures[i].material.shading = THREE.SmoothShading;
            figures[i].material.needsUpdate = true;
            figures[i].geometry.normalsNeedUpdate = true;
            console.log(figures[i].geometry);
        }
    }
}

var i = 0;
function display() {
    resetState();
    changeLightning(direc_intensity);
    changeMaterial(change_material);
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    render();
    render2();
    VRinit();
}

function animate() {
    update();
    display();
}

function createCube(obj,x,y,z)
{
    const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 2, 2, 2 );
    const material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {color: 0xff0000} );
    material.shading = THREE.FlatShading;
    material.shading = THREE.SmoothShading;
    geometry.normalsNeedUpdate = true;
    geometry.computeVertexNormals();
    const cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    cube.position.set(x,y,z);
    obj.add(cube);
    figures.push(cube);
}

function createFig1(obj,x,y,z)
{
    //creates 1st figure
    
    //creates lower left triangle
    createMesh(obj,'triangle',2,0,0,0,0,Math.PI/180*90,0,1);
    createMesh(obj,'triangle',2,0,0,0,0,Math.PI/180*20,0,1);
    obj.position.set(x,y,z);

    universe.add(obj);
}

function createDirectionalLight(obj)
{
    directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 0.6);
    directionalLight.position.set(0, 45, 45);
    let lightHelper = new THREE.DirectionalLightHelper(directionalLight);
    directionalLight.name="light";
    obj.add( directionalLight );
    obj.add( lightHelper );
}

function createScene() {
    scene[0] = new THREE.Scene();
    scene[0].add(new THREE.AxesHelper(100));

    universe = new THREE.Object3D();
    universe.scale.set(1,1,1);

    direc_light = new THREE.Object3D();
    direc_light.name="directional";
    createDirectionalLight(direc_light);
    direc_light.rotateZ(Math.PI/180*30);
    console.log(direc_light);
    universe.add(direc_light);
    
    palanque = new THREE.Object3D();
    directionalLight.target = palanque;
    universe.add(palanque);
    createFloor(palanque,0,0,0);
    createPalanque(palanque,0,2,0);

    createCube(universe,0,4.5+1,5);
    createCube(universe,0,4.5+1,0);
    createCube(universe,0,4.5+1,-5);

    const light = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x404040 ); // soft white light
    universe.add( light );

    fig1 = new THREE.Object3D();
    //createFig1(fig1,10,10,10);

    fig2 = new THREE.Object3D();
    //createFig1(fig2,20,1,1);

    universe.position.set(0,0,0);
    scene[0].add(universe);
    //createMesh('triangle',1,0,10,0.8,0,-Math.PI/180*45,0);
}

function createOrtographicCamera(x, y, z) {

    var val = 2;
    aspectRatio = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    var camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera( viewSize * aspectRatio/-val, 
                                                                                    viewSize * aspectRatio / val, 
                                                                                    viewSize / val, 
                                                                                    viewSize / -val, 
                                                                                    1, 
                                                                                    1000);
    camera.position.x = x;
    camera.position.y = y;
    camera.position.z = z;
    
    camera.lookAt(scene[0].position);
    
    return camera;
}

//creates a new scene with Pause Mode
function createPauseMessage() {
    scene[1] = new THREE.Scene();
  
    let spriteMap = new THREE.TextureLoader().load('./media/pauseScreen.png');
    let spriteMaterial = new THREE.SpriteMaterial({
        map: spriteMap
    });
    let message = new THREE.Sprite(spriteMaterial);
    let scaleRatio = 100 * window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    message.scale.set(scaleRatio, scaleRatio, 0);
    message.visible = true;
    message.position.set(0, 0, 20);
  
    scene[1].add(message);
}

function createPerspectiveCamera(x, y, z) {
    aspectRatio = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70,
                                                                                    aspectRatio,
                                                                                    1,
                                                                                    1000);
    camera.position.x = x;
    camera.position.y = y;
    camera.position.z = z;
    
    camera.lookAt(scene[0].position);
    
    return camera;
}

function onKeyDown(e) {
    var keyName = e.keyCode;
    switch (keyName) {
        case 49://1
            if(!pause)
                currentCamera = 0;
            break;
        case 50://2
            if(!pause)
                currentCamera = 1;
            break;

        case 81: //Q
        case 113: //q
            qKey = true;
            break;
        case 87: //W
        case 119: //w
            wKey = true;
            break;          
        
        case 69: //E
        case 101: //e
            eKey = true;
            break;
        case 82: //R
        case 114: //r
            rKey = true;
            break;      
            
        case 84: //T
        case 116: //t
            tKey = true;
            break;
        case 89: //Y
        case 121: //y
            yKey = true;
            break;      
        
        case 68:  //D
        case 100: //d
            if(!pause)
                direc_intensity = (direc_intensity == 0 ? 0.5 : 0);
            break;
        
        case 65://A
        case 97://a
            if(!pause)
                change_material = !change_material;
            break;
        
        case 77:
        case 109:
            if (pause)
                reset=true;
            break;

        case 83:    // Pause
        case 115:
            pause = !pause;
            break;

        case 52://4
            wires = !wires;
            break;
    
        case 37 : // left arrow key
            leftArrow = true;
            break;
        case 38: // up arrow key
            upArrow = true;
            break;
        case 39: // right arrow key
            rightArrow = true;
            break;
        case 40: // down arrow key
            downArrow = true;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

function onKeyUp(e) {
    var keyName = e.keyCode;
    switch (keyName) {
        case 37 : // left arrow key
            leftArrow = false;
            break;
        case 38: // up arrow key
            upArrow = false;
            break;
        case 39: // right arrow key
            rightArrow = false;
            break;
        case 40: // down arrow key
            downArrow = false;
            break;

        case 81: //Q
        case 113: //q
            qKey = false;
            break;
        case 87: //W
        case 119: //w
            wKey = false;
            break;          
        
        case 69: //E
        case 101: //e
            eKey = false;
            break;

        case 82: //R
        case 114: //r
            rKey = false;
            break;      
        case 84: //T
        case 116: //t
            tKey = false;
            break;
        case 89: //Y
        case 121: //y
            yKey = false;
            break;          
        default:
            break;
    }
}

function resetState()
{
    if (pause)
    {
        if(reset)
        {
            change_material = true;
            changeMaterial(change_material);
            for(i=0;i<figures.length;i++)
                figures[i].rotation.y = 0;
            direc_intensity=0.5;
            changeLightning(direc_intensity);
        }
    }
    reset=false;
}

function createOrtogonalCamera(x, y, z) {
    // Adjusts camera ratio so the scene is totally visible 
    // OrthographicCamera( left, right, top, bottom, near, far )
    camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(window.innerWidth / -(2 * cameraRatio),
        window.innerWidth / (2 * cameraRatio), window.innerHeight / (2 * cameraRatio),
        window.innerHeight / -(2 * cameraRatio), 0, 1000);

    camera.position.x = x;
    camera.position.y = y;
    camera.position.z = z;
    camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(-x, -y, z));
    return camera;
}

function VRinit()
{
    if (renderer.xr.getSession())
    {
        renderer.setAnimationLoop( function () {
            renderer.render( scene[0], camera[currentCamera] );
        } );
    }
}

function init() {
        
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
    document.body.appendChild( VRButton.createButton( renderer ) );
    renderer.xr.enabled = true;
    
    createScene();
    OrtogonalCamera = createOrtogonalCamera(0, 100, 20);
    OrtogonalCamera2 = createOrtogonalCamera(0, 10, 10);
    camera[0] = createPerspectiveCamera(viewSize/1.5,viewSize/4,0);
    camera[1] = createOrtographicCamera(0, viewSize,0);
    camera[2] = new THREE.StereoCamera();
    controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera[currentCamera], renderer.domElement);
    animate();
    createPauseMessage();

    window.addEventListener("resize", onResize);
    window.addEventListener("keydown", onKeyDown);
    window.addEventListener("keyup", onKeyUp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

MeshPhongMaterial needs lights in scene to be visible.

```
const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 1);
scene.add(ambientLight);
```